# Looking up a string in a file, then copying lines after it

Tags: java

This is my first time posting to this site, so if I get any formatting wrong, please be easy on me Lol

I'm writing a Java program that needs to look up a part number from an inventory, and then print the part number along with the data following it. The code is only printing out the information at the top of the file, and then repeating my else  statement 5 times.

Here is the code:

```
package inventory;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class inventory 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // File Information
    String parts;
    File inventoryFile;
    FileWriter inventoryFW;
    PrintWriter inventoryPW;
    Scanner inventorySC;

    //User Information
    String userChoice;

    // Part Information
    String partID, partFileID, partFileDesc, partFileLoc, partDesc, partLoc;
    double partFilePrice, partPrice;
    int partFileQuan, partQuan;

    userChoice = ("A");

    // Loop
    if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
        System.exit(0);
    else
        while(!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
        {
            // Get Employee Decision
            System.out.println("Please choose a letter: \n"
                               + "L - Look Up Part \n"
                               + "A - Add to Inventory File \n"
                               + "E - Erase From Inventory File \n" 
                               + "G - Generate a Sales Slip \n"
                               + "I - Add Quantity to Inventory File \n"
                               + "D - Display Inventory \n"
                               + "Q - Quit \n"
                               + "Selection: ");
            userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();

            // Process User Choice
            if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
            { // Choice L
                // Look Up Part
                System.out.println("Enter Part I.D. Number: ");
                partID = keyboard.nextLine();

                // Do until partID is equal to partFileID
                parts = "inventoryFile.txt";
                inventoryFile = new File(parts);
                inventorySC = new Scanner(inventoryFile);

                partFileID = "0";
                partFileDesc = "0";
                partFilePrice = 0;
                partFileLoc = "0";
                partFileQuan = 0;


                while(inventorySC.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String lineFromFile = inventorySC.nextLine();
                    if(lineFromFile.contains(partID))
                    {

                        partFileDesc = inventorySC.nextLine();
                        partFilePrice = inventorySC.nextDouble();
                        inventorySC.nextLine();
                        partFileLoc = inventorySC.nextLine();
                        partFileQuan = inventorySC.nextInt();

                        System.out.println("Part I.D. Number: " + partFileID + "\n");
                          System.out.println("Part Description: " + partFileDesc + "\n"
                                   + "Part Price: " + partFilePrice + "\n"
                                   + "Part Location: " + partFileLoc + "\n"
                                   + "Part Quantity: " + partFileQuan);
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("Sorry, this part cannot be found");

                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

And here is the datafile I am trying to pull from:

```
1234567
Clutch
45.68
Warehouse B
8
1234
Brake
66.78
Warehouse A
4
```

For example, if the user entered part number "1234" the program should search for that part number in the file, and then display:

```
1234
Brake
66.78
Warehouse A
4
```

Sorry about any poor code formatting, I have been fighting with this for a while now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `1234567` contains `1234` ... maybe consider using `equals` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues.

1. The contains will have multiple matches.
2. You will print "not found every line" you don't find.
3. You are not breaking out of the loop.

---

```
boolean found = false;
while(inventorySC.hasNextLine()){
    String lineFromFile = inventorySC.nextLine();
    if(lineFromFile.equals(partID)) {       
     partFileDesc = inventorySC.nextLine();
     partFilePrice = inventorySC.nextLine();
     partFileLoc = inventorySC.nextLine();
     partFileQuan = inventorySC.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Part I.D. Number: " + partFileID + "\n");
                              System.out.println("Part Description: " + partFileDesc + "\n"
                                       + "Part Price: " + partFilePrice + "\n"
                                       + "Part Location: " + partFileLoc + "\n"
                                       + "Part Quantity: " + partFileQuan);
                              found = true;
                             break;
                        }
            }

if(!found)
    System.out.println("Sorry, this part cannot be found");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are only skipping to the next line if the part list doesn't contain your part value.  You actually want to skip down 5 lines if the part is not on the 'next line'.

In your "else" statement, you'll just want to call the inventorySC.nextLine(); 4 more times to get to the next place in the file you actually want to check for a part number.

If you want the 'not found' condition to reflect more effectively that the part number actually wasn't found at all, you'll want to move that message to after it could have scanned the whole file.  Set a boolean with a name like 'found' to false before the file scan.  If you enter your 'contains' condition because there is a part number in the file that contains your input, set the 'found' equal to true.

At the end if the 'found' is still 'false', you can output the 'not found' message.

Answer (score 0):

As MadProgrammer commented above, you'll need to use 'equals' instead of 'contains'- this is why you match on the first entry. When you find a match and output it, you need to exit the while loop using a 'break' - otherwise you output the else value for each line left over (as is happening to you). But there is one other problem in that you may need to read an entire record - not just the first line of the record - when there is no match so you don't get screwed up when an inventory item has a quantity of 1234 when searching for part number 1234.